What Functions Are Supported by the Android Management API (AMAPI) Extensibility SDK for Companion Apps?
I am developing a solution to manage Android devices using the Android Management API (AMAPI).
I’ve reviewed the Android Management API's Extensibility SDK documentation, but I’m unclear on its purpose beyond executing commands like clearing app data, as mentioned in the documentation.
My question is: What functions and commands are supported by this SDK?
The documentation is unclear, as it lacks detailed information of the Android Management API Extensibility SDK and its functionalities.

Currently the SDK supports a local command to clear app data, and a package to allow EMMs using legacy DPCs to migrate to Android Device Policy. You can check the release notes for the library to know when new features are added. You may refer to this AMAPI extensibility sample app for additional information. This app provides a fully functional example of Integrating with AMAPI SDK to make use of extensibility features.
